Work with data filtered by Slicers in Google Sheets?
I have a worksheet on Google Sheets:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H9a_RXI41OWFciCZnlfrUD66bTzh6jl2SOL01gwXUMQ/copy
I have two slicers.
One is to load questions based on category, and the other is to filter by whether the question was selected or not.
In the above sheet, I would like to set the slicer for the category to "Mindset and Motivation" for example, and load the filtered questions on to I4:J13
However, I am not able to figure out how to work with the filtered data.
I have tried to work with getHiddenRows(), but I am still stuck trying to figure this out.
Here's what I tried:
function getRandomQuestions() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Webinar Questions'); // Replace 'Sheet1' with the name of your sheet
  
  // Get the range of filtered questions
  var range = sheet.getRange('F16:J'); // Adjust the range as per your data
  
  // Get the filter object applied to the range
  var filter = range.getFilter();
  
  // Check if a filter exists
  if (filter) {
    // Get the indices of hidden rows
    var hiddenRows = filter.getHiddenRows();
    
    // Get the visible rows by filtering out hidden rows
    var visibleRows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < range.getNumRows(); i++) {
      if (!hiddenRows.includes(i + 1)) { // Add 1 to convert from 0-based index to 1-based index
        visibleRows.push(i + 1);
      }
    }
    
    // Construct the visible range using the visible row indices
    var visibleRange = range.offset(visibleRows[0] - 1, 0, visibleRows.length, range.getNumColumns()); // Adjust the starting index to 1-based
    
    // Get the values of the visible range
    var values = visibleRange.getValues();
  } else {
    // If no filter is applied, use the values directly from the range
    var values = range.getValues();
  }
  
  // Check if there are existing questions in the destination range
  var existingQuestions = sheet.getRange('I4:I13').getValues().filter(function(row) {
    return row[0] !== ''; // Filter out empty rows
  });

  // Update the "Used?" column for existing questions with checkboxes checked
  existingQuestions.forEach(function(row, index) {
    var question = row[0];
    var checkboxValue = sheet.getRange('J' + (index + 4)).getValue(); // Get checkbox value
    
    // Use VLOOKUP to find the row index of the question
    var rowIndex = vlookupQuestion(question, values);
    
    // If row index found and checkbox value is 'Yes', update the "Used?" column
    if (rowIndex !== -1 && checkboxValue === 'Yes') {
      sheet.getRange('J' + (visibleRows[rowIndex] + 3)).setValue('Yes'); // Adjust the index to 1-based
    }
  });

  // Filter the rows based on the "Used?" column
  var filteredValues = values.filter(function(row) {
    // Assuming "Yes" represents used and "No" represents unused
    return row[4] !== 'Yes'; // Adjust the condition based on your data
  });

  // Shuffle the filtered values
  filteredValues.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
  
  // Select only the first two columns (Questions and Used?)
  var selectedQuestions = filteredValues.map(function(row) {
    return [row[0], row[4]]; // Select only the first and fifth columns
  });

  // Remove any blank rows from selected questions
  selectedQuestions = selectedQuestions.filter(function(row) {
    return row[0] !== ''; // Filter out rows with empty questions
  });
  
  // Pad selected questions with blank rows if less than 10
  while (selectedQuestions.length < 10) {
    selectedQuestions.push(['', '']); // Add blank rows to make up 10 questions
  }
  
  // Truncate selected questions if more than 10
  selectedQuestions = selectedQuestions.slice(0, 10);

  // Get the range where you want to paste the selected questions
  var destinationRange = sheet.getRange('I4:J13'); // Adjust the range as per your requirement
  
  // Clear the previous data
  destinationRange.clearContent(); // Clear content only, preserving formatting
  
  // Paste the selected questions
  destinationRange.setValues(selectedQuestions); // Set values from selected questions
  
  // Get the range where you want to paste the checkbox values
  var checkboxRange = sheet.getRange('J4:J13'); // Adjust the range as per your requirement
  
  // Clear the previous checkbox values
  checkboxRange.clearContent(); // Clear content only, preserving formatting

  // Extract the checkbox values preserving existing formatting
  var checkboxValues = selectedQuestions.map(function(row) {
    return [row[1]]; // Extract checkbox values
  });
  
  // Set the checkbox values preserving existing formatting
  checkboxRange.setValues(checkboxValues); // Set checkbox values
}

// Function to perform VLOOKUP to find the row index of the question
function vlookupQuestion(question, values) {
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] === question) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1; // Return -1 if question is not found
}

I've thought of using isRowHiddenByFilter to go through each row and see if it was filtered or not but takes a lot of time and I don't think it is the best way to do it.
I think this solution: Doesn't sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(n) work with slicers?
Might work but I am a bit confused on how to apply it here.
Appreciate any help I can get.
Edit:
Code used with isRowHiddenByFilter()
function getRandomQuestions() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Webinar Questions');
  var range = sheet.getRange('F16:J');
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  // Get the filtered rows
  var visibleRows = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (!sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 16)) { // Check if the row is hidden by filter
      visibleRows.push(values[i]);
    }
  }
  
  // Check if there are existing questions in the destination range
  var existingQuestions = sheet.getRange('I4:I13').getValues().filter(function(row) {
    return row[0] !== '';
  });

  existingQuestions.forEach(function(row, index) {
    var question = row[0];
    var checkboxValue = sheet.getRange('J' + (index + 4)).getValue();
    var rowIndex = vlookupQuestion(question, visibleRows);
    if (rowIndex !== -1 && checkboxValue === 'Yes') {
      sheet.getRange('J' + (rowIndex + 16)).setValue('Yes');
    }
  });

  var selectedQuestions = visibleRows.map(function(row) {
    return [row[0], row[4]];
  });

  selectedQuestions = selectedQuestions.filter(function(row) {
    return row[0] !== '';
  });

  while (selectedQuestions.length < 10) {
    selectedQuestions.push(['', '']);
  }
  
  selectedQuestions = selectedQuestions.slice(0, 10);

  var destinationRange = sheet.getRange('I4:J13');
  destinationRange.clearContent();
  destinationRange.setValues(selectedQuestions);
  
  var checkboxRange = sheet.getRange('J4:J13');
  checkboxRange.clearContent();

  var checkboxValues = selectedQuestions.map(function(row) {
    return [row[1]];
  });
  
  checkboxRange.setValues(checkboxValues);
}

function vlookupQuestion(question, values) {
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] === question) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}


First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About your question, from I've thought of using isRowHiddenByFilter to go through each row and see if it was filtered or not but takes a lot of time and I don't think it is the best way to do it., you want to achieve your goal without using isRowHiddenByFilter. Is my understanding correct? By the way, about takes a lot of time, can you provide the details of both the processing time and the script you tested?

I would like to use isRowHiddenByFilter to filter out hidden rows and only pull from visible rows. As for using isRowHiddenByFilter to go through each row and see if it was filtered or not, I've let it run for around a few mins and it was still executing it, ending with a "Exceeded maximum execution time" error.
Added the code I used for isRowHiddenByFilter to OP.

Thank you for replying. About isRowHiddenByFilter in your situation, I understood it. If you want to use my answer, it is required to set the current slicer as "Set current filters as default", and to set the basic filter. By this, the filtered rows can be obtained with isRowHiddenByFilter. Because isRowHiddenByFilter cannot be used to the slicer as I have already mentioned in my answer. In your added script, I cannot find about it. How about this?

Unfortunately, in the current stage, the current slicer cannot be set to "Set current filters as default" using a script. In this case, it is required to manuallly set. If you want to use my approach, please be careful about this.

I see. Do you mean to say that it can only be used with the default slicer settings, and not the ones we set dynamically?
Currently, I have set all options to be default. But if I override that and only select 1 option, it doesn't work. Is this what you've found as well?

Thank you for replying. About Do you mean to say that it can only be used with the default slicer settings, and not the ones we set dynamically?, it's yes. About Currently, I have set all options to be default., I cannot understand it.
